# davis.js with full address links

Tags: javascript, html, url, browser-history

i am trying to use davis.js history plugin but i have problem (using codeigniter, but that isn't important).

```
var app = Davis(function () {
this.get('http://localhost/folder/controller/:id', function (req) {
        alert("Hello " + req.params['id'])
    })
})

app.start()
```

and link:

```
<a href="http://localhost/folder/controller/2">ID</a>
```

in this way it doesn't work, becouse it is full address, how can i make davis to look full address ?

Or you can suggest me another plugin ?

Comment: I haven't seen Davis being used with full urls like this before, it was designed to be used with paths e.g. '/foo/bar', although I can't think of anything that would specifically prevent Davis from working with the full url.  Are you getting error messages?

Comment: It just redirect me to that address, i need to use full address with framework :( is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for relative urls..

Comment: Can you post the solution it may be helpful to others

Comment: I make $config['base_folder'] with falue of ci "folder", and new helper create_url($segment), which works just like base_url but it will use that value from config and segment, and put them together.. so url will be valid.